# Can Stargate handle high traffic?

Tags: rest, cassandra, traffic, stargate-oss

I am working on an application that have to handle over 2 million requests per day. If I have 3 Stargate apps (rest api) run on 3 different servers connect to data center with 4 nodes of Cassandra database. Do you think Stargate can handle that volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Stargate can handle high traffic.

Stargate isn't going to be the bottleneck since it's really just another client. What matters is the throughput of your cluster.

You need to size your cluster to handle the throughput you require. For example, if your 4-node cluster can handle 100K operations per second but your app requires 200K ops/s then you need to double the number of nodes in your cluster. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick. In my case, I am not worry much about Cassandra because It can handle that volume in our other projects. With this new project, by some reasons, we want to use Stargate to stay between our app and Cassandra. Do you think: when 2 million requests (per day) come to Stargate, Is Stargate able to write/read data to cassandra and returns data to our app without any issue?

Comment: Absolutely. 2M/day is not a problem at all. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Some quick math, 2 million requests per day comes out to roughly 23 requests per second. I've seen the Stargate REST API handle ~25k op/s in a 3 Stargate and 6 Cassandra cluster with virtually no tuning (testing performed with [nosqlbench](https://github.com/nosqlbench/nosqlbench/blob/main/driver-http/src/main/resources/activities/baselines/http-rest-keyvalue.yaml). So I believe it should be able to handle your workload.

Stargate performance will depend on multiple factors like resources allocated, workload, and as Erick mentions above the throughput of your backing cluster.